# How to use a PyTorch model without calculating gradients?

Tags: memory-leaks, gpu, pytorch

I found a line of code in [this file](https://github.com/liorshk/facenet_pytorch/blob/master/train_triplet.py):

```
out_a, out_p, out_n = model(data_a), model(data_p), model(data_n)
```

As you can see the `forward()` function is invoked multiple times before `backward()`,In my test,the GPU consumption will increase accordingly,so GPU memory leaking happens. The questions here are:

1. How to solve this problem?
2. Is it possible use model as a pure feature extractor for these three consecutive invoking (with some modification,of course),then in fourth invoking,use it as `forward()`,if "Yes",how to implement it?

Comment: Am I getting this correctly that you simply want to compute the `out_X` values, and then use them in the fourth call for your backward computation?
Have you already looked into `model.eval()` (I think there might be a different pattern for newer PyTorch versions)?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the already proposed answer you can also locally disable gradient computation by using `torch.no_grad()`:

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    out_a, out_p, out_n = model(data_a), model(data_p), model(data_n)
```

---

This also prevents any gradient calculations within the `with` statement and thus reduces memory usage significantly:

> Context-manager that disabled gradient calculation.
>
> Disabling gradient calculation is useful for inference, when you are
>   sure that you will not call `Tensor.backward()`. It will reduce memory
>   consumption for computations that would otherwise have
>   *requires_grad=True*. In this mode, the result of every computation will
>   have *requires_grad=False*, even when the inputs have
>   *requires_grad=True*.

*Source: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.no_grad*

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to take the model as a pure feature extractor (i.e., no update during the process), here are something you can do

Assuming you have a model, `model`, you'd like to set it to the evaluation mode first.

```
model = FeatureExtractor().cuda()
mode.eval()
```

Next, to decrease the comsuption of gpu memory, you need to stop gradient accumulation and computation.

```
for p in model.parameters():
    p.require_grads = False
out_a, out_p, out_n = model(data_a), model(data_p), model(data_n)
```

Then, I guess your problem will be solved. Note that, there is "no" gradient you can backprop through `out_a`, `out_p`, and `out_n`.